# pipenv and OS X Monterey - can't install dependencies from Pipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew, pipenv

I am running OS X Monterey 12.6.3 and I installed pipenv 2023.2.4 via brew with `brew install pipenv`.

I have the following [Pipfile](https://github.com/Evo-Learning-project/sai_evo_backend/blob/master/Pipfile) and [Pipfile.lock](https://github.com/Evo-Learning-project/sai_evo_backend/blob/master/Pipfile.lock), which I have been able to run `pipenv install` on on other machines.

If I run `pipenv install` on the repository containing those files, the output ends with a bunch of failed dependencies which all look like this:

```
An error occurred while installing zipp==3.11.0 ; python_version >= '3.7' --hash=sha256:a7a22e05929290a67401440b39690ae6563279bced5f314609d9d03798f56766 --hash=sha256:83a28fcb75844b5c0cdaf5aa4003c2d728c77e05f5aeabe8e95e56727005fbaa! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing zope.interface==5.5.2 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4' --hash=sha256:8a2ffadefd0e7206adc86e492ccc60395f7edb5680adedf17a7ee4205c530df4 --hash=sha256:0217a9615531c83aeedb12e126611b1b1a3175013bbafe57c702ce40000eb9a0 --hash=sha256:e1574980b48c8c74f83578d1e77e701f8439a5d93f36a5a0af31337467c08fcf --hash=sha256:6e972493cdfe4ad0411fd9abfab7d4d800a7317a93928217f1a5de2bb0f0d87a --hash=sha256:4087e253bd3bbbc3e615ecd0b6dd03c4e6a1e46d152d3be6d2ad08fbad742dcc --hash=sha256:7e66f60b0067a10dd289b29dceabd3d0e6d68be1504fc9d0bc209cf07f56d189 --hash=sha256:40f4065745e2c2fa0dff0e7ccd7c166a8ac9748974f960cd39f63d2c19f9231f --hash=sha256:765d703096ca47aa5d93044bf701b00bbce4d903a95b41fff7c3796e747b1f1d --hash=sha256:a16025df73d24795a0bde05504911d306307c24a64187752685ff6ea23897cb0 --hash=sha256:fb68d212efd057596dee9e6582daded9f8ef776538afdf5feceb3059df2d2e7b --hash=sha256:f0980d44b8aded808bec5059018d64692f0127f10510eca71f2f0ace8fb11188 --hash=sha256:959697ef2757406bff71467a09d940ca364e724c534efbf3786e86eee8591452 --hash=sha256:7579960be23d1fddecb53898035a0d112ac858c3554018ce615cefc03024e46d --hash=sha256:604cdba8f1983d0ab78edc29aa71c8df0ada06fb147cea436dc37093a0100a4e --hash=sha256:0fb497c6b088818e3395e302e426850f8236d8d9f4ef5b2836feae812a8f699c --hash=sha256:d692374b578360d36568dd05efb8a5a67ab6d1878c29c582e37ddba80e66c396 --hash=sha256:5334e2ef60d3d9439c08baedaf8b84dc9bb9522d0dacbc10572ef5609ef8db6d --hash=sha256:008b0b65c05993bb08912f644d140530e775cf1c62a072bf9340c2249e613c32 --hash=sha256:17ebf6e0b1d07ed009738016abf0d0a0f80388e009d0ac6e0ead26fc162b3b9c --hash=sha256:d169ccd0756c15bbb2f1acc012f5aab279dffc334d733ca0d9362c5beaebe88e --hash=sha256:d514c269d1f9f5cd05ddfed15298d6c418129f3f064765295659798349c43e6f --hash=sha256:a2ad597c8c9e038a5912ac3cf166f82926feff2f6e0dabdab956768de0a258f5 --hash=sha256:dc26c8d44472e035d59d6f1177eb712888447f5799743da9c398b0339ed90b1b --hash=sha256:f98d4bd7bbb15ca701d19b93263cc5edfd480c3475d163f137385f49e5b3a3a7 --hash=sha256:e74a578172525c20d7223eac5f8ad187f10940dac06e40113d62f14f3adb1e8f --hash=sha256:e945de62917acbf853ab968d8916290548df18dd62c739d862f359ecd25842a6 --hash=sha256:dbaeb9cf0ea0b3bc4b36fae54a016933d64c6d52a94810a63c00f440ecb37dd7 --hash=sha256:696f3d5493eae7359887da55c2afa05acc3db5fc625c49529e84bd9992313296 --hash=sha256:9d783213fab61832dbb10d385a319cb0e45451088abd45f95b5bb88ed0acca1a --hash=sha256:6373d7eb813a143cb7795d3e42bd8ed857c82a90571567e681e1b3841a390d16 --hash=sha256:65c3c06afee96c654e590e046c4a24559e65b0a87dbff256cd4bd6f77e1a33f9 --hash=sha256:404d1e284eda9e233c90128697c71acffd55e183d70628aa0bbb0e7a3084ed8b --hash=sha256:3218ab1a7748327e08ef83cca63eea7cf20ea7e2ebcb2522072896e5e2fceedf --hash=sha256:311196634bb9333aa06f00fc94f59d3a9fddd2305c2c425d86e406ddc6f2260d --hash=sha256:bfee1f3ff62143819499e348f5b8a7f3aa0259f9aca5e0ddae7391d059dce671 --hash=sha256:655796a906fa3ca67273011c9805c1e1baa047781fca80feeb710328cdbed87f! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies...
```

I tried uninstalling pipenv and reinstalling it, upgrading brew, deleting and recreating the environment... nothing has worked.

So I tried deleting the Pipfile.lock file and recreating it.

Running `pipenv lock` on the given Pipfile ends with this:

```
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠧ Locking...
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 811, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 759, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 738, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1102, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 899, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 687, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed
```

Running any of `pipenv lock --pre`, `pipenv lock --clear`, and `pipenv lock --pre --clear` yields the same results.

Running `pipenv lock --pre --clear --verbose` yields an output which ends like this:
(I cut the first several lines which look all like the first ones here, just with different dependencies)

```
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('django-silk'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('django-silk'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('django-stubs'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('django-stubs'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangochannelsrestframework'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangochannelsrestframework'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangorestframework~=3.13'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangorestframework~=3.13'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangorestframework-stubs'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('djangorestframework-stubs'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-access-policy~=1.0'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-access-policy~=1.0'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-nested-routers'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-nested-routers'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-social-oauth2'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-social-oauth2'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-viewset-profiler'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-viewset-profiler'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-yasg'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('drf-yasg'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('gunicorn'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('gunicorn'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('markdown'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('markdown'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('opencv-python'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('opencv-python'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('pillow'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('pillow'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('prompt-toolkit'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('prompt-toolkit'), None)
Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('psycopg2'), None)
INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.reporter:Reporter.adding_requirement(SpecifierRequirement('psycopg2'), None)
ERROR:pip.subprocessor: python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/build/metadata_legacy.py", line 64, in generate_metadata
    call_subprocess(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 224, in call_subprocess
    raise error
pipenv.patched.pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationSubprocessError: python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 685, in resolve
    results = resolver.resolve(self.constraints, check_supported_wheels=False)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache = LinkCandidate(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 301, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 232, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 312, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 577, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 69, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 61, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 542, in prepare_metadata
    self.metadata_directory = generate_metadata_legacy(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_internal/operations/build/metadata_legacy.py", line 71, in generate_metadata
    raise MetadataGenerationFailed(package_details=details) from error
pipenv.patched.pip._internal.exceptions.MetadataGenerationFailed: metadata generation failed
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 845, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 831, in main
    _main(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 811, in _main
    resolve_packages(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 759, in resolve_packages
    results, resolver = resolve(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 738, in resolve
    return resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1102, in resolve_deps
    results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 899, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2023.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 687, in resolve
    raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: [31m[1mERROR[0m: [33mmetadata generation failed[0m
✘ Locking Failed!
⠹ Locking...
```

Finally, `pipenv install --skip-lock` and then `pipenv graph` yields:
https://gist.github.com/samul-1/513e6ee5a554748ed2e72f916227319c

I also tried using different versions of python, forcing them with pyenv... I also browsed all github issues and SO questions I could find on the matter.

I have no idea what else to try. Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue had something to do with `psycopg`.

Running `brew install postgresql` and then trying to `pipenv install` solved it.